# Xcode, get ride of Unknown sequence?

Tags: javascript, ios, replace

```
    NSString* attribute_list = [wvPage stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
            @"var attrs=document.getElementsByClassName('attributes-list')[0].innerHTML;attrs = attrs.replace(/(?:<\!\-\-[^\-]*\-\->|<li[^>]*>|&nbsp;|\ )/ig, '');attrs = attrs.replace(/<\/li[^>]*>/ig, '|');"];
```

Above is my code. I want to do replace in JavaScript.

Things work fine, but I'm getting warnings. How can I ban these warnings?

```
Unknown escape sequence '\!'
Unknown escape sequence '\-'
...
```

and things like this.

Comment: What warnings are you getting?

Comment: @SetFreeByTruth sorry I forgot to post it.

Comment: Did you escape these: "\" becomes "\\"?

Comment: @qegal I don't understand. The js code runs ok in browser, I need to change the js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a string `@""` which allows special escaped characters (e.g. think of how `\n` magically becomes a new-line).  This means *every* backslash in your code that is not meant to be parsed in this way must be *doubled* so that it is kept verbatim.

For example:

```
@"var attrs=document.getElementsByClassName('attributes-list')[0].innerHTML;attrs = attrs.replace(/(?:<\\!\\-\\-[^\\-]*\\-\\->|<li[^>]*>|&nbsp;|\\ )/ig, '');attrs = attrs.replace(/<\\/li[^>]*>/ig, '|');"];
```